# How to count occurences of values in a nested array?

Tags: mongodb

I've searched but could not find an answer to my problem. I need to count the occurences of the field "nationalCode". I've got a collection with this sample structure in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7519cc6c17d65d4983f048"),
   "origin" : "Base1",
    "topic" : [ 
        {
            "nationalTopic" : {
                "nationalCode" : 26
            },
            "dateTime" : NumberLong(20120927000000)
        }, 
        {
            "nationalTopic" : {
                "nationalCode" : 132
            },
            "dateTime" : NumberLong(20120927000000)
        }, 
        {
            "nationalTopic" : {
                "nationalCode" : 26
            },
            "dateTime" : NumberLong(20120927000000)
        }, 
        {
            "nationalTopic" : {
                "nationalCode" : 26
            },
            "dateTime" : NumberLong(20121005000000)
        }

    ]
}
```

I've used the following code (I tried many variations of it, but none of them got me the right results):

```
db.processos.aggregate( 
  [
     { "$unwind": "$topic" },
     {"$match": {"origin": "Base1"}},
     {"$group": { "_id": { nationalCode: "$topic.nationalTopic.nationalCode",  "count": { "$sum": 1 }} } }

  ]
)
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "nationalCode" : 26,
        "count" : 3.0
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "nationalCode" : 132,
        "count" : 1.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the count element from the _id.

The following query worked for me.

```
db.data.aggregate( 
  [
     { "$unwind": "$topic" },
     {"$match": {"origin": "Base1"}},
     {"$group": { _id: { "nationalCode": "$topic.nationalTopic.nationalCode" },
         "count": {$sum: 1} }
     }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

just  do  it with  `$project`  to  change  your  format

do it like this

```
MongoDB Enterprise >
 db.ggg.aggregate(
[
{$unwind:"$topic"},
{"$match": {"origin": "Base1"}},
{"$group": { "_id": { nationalCode: "$topic.nationalTopic.nationalCode"}, 
 "count": { "$sum": 1 } }},
{$project :{"_id.nationalCode":1,"_id.count":"$count"}}
]
)
```

here it the result !

```
{ "_id" : { "nationalCode" : 26, "count" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "nationalCode" : 132, "count" : 1 } }
```